# latitude and longitude returning null in mapmyindia eLocation

Tags: java, android, mapmyindia-api

I am trying to get latitude and longitude using autosuggest API on MapMyndia but it returns to null

```
private void callAutoSuggestApi(String searchString) {
        MapmyIndiaAutoSuggest.builder()
                .query(searchString)
                .build()
                .enqueueCall(new Callback<AutoSuggestAtlasResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<AutoSuggestAtlasResponse> call,
                                           @NonNull Response<AutoSuggestAtlasResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                ArrayList<ELocation> suggestedList = response.body().getSuggestedLocations();
                                
                                if (suggestedList.size() > 0) {
                                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    AutoSuggestAdapter autoSuggestAdapter = new AutoSuggestAdapter(suggestedList, eLocation -> {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + eLocation.toString());
                                        selectedPlace(eLocation);
                                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    });
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(autoSuggestAdapter);
                                }
                            } else {
                                showToast("Not able to get value, Try again.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<AutoSuggestAtlasResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                        showToast(t.toString());
                    }
                });

    }
```

**The output I'm getting**

> ELocation{poiId='GA9HE8', placeAddress='Chamarajanagar District, Karnataka', latitude='null', longitude='null', level=0, type='SUB_DISTRICT', typeX=0, placeName='Yelandur', entryLatitude=null, entryLongitude=null, explore=-1, photoCount=0, user='null', source='null', time=0, index=0, alternateName='', keywords=[], addressTokens=null, p=0, orderIndex=7}

Comment: Please include a [mre], including such things as the search query.

Comment: search query is Yelandur

Comment: They are pushing us to use ELoc. U have poiId in respose. You can use that to place marker and in other APIs